# Bound for $\prod_i^\infty(1+x_i)$ if $\sum_i^\infty x_i$ converges to $L$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Here's the question, and I want to know if my steps are correct:

> Assume $x_i \geq 0$. If  $\sum_i^\infty x_i$ converges, show that $\prod_i^\infty(1+x_i)$ converges as well.

**Attempt:** Since $\prod_i^\infty(1+x_i)$ is monotone increasing, we just need to find an upper bound for $\prod_i^\infty(1+x_i)$.

Suppose $\sum_i^\infty x_i=L$, then we have $\sum_i^M x_i \leq L$ for some $M \in \mathbb{N}$. Using AM-GM, we obtain:

\begin{align}
\left( \prod_i^M(1+x_i)\right)^\frac{1}{M} &\leq \frac{(1+x_1)+(1+x_2)+\cdots+(1+x_M)}{M} \\
& \leq \frac{M+\sum_i^M x_i}{M} \\
&\leq \frac{M+L}{M} \\ 
&= 1+\frac{L}{M}
\end{align}

Raising both sides by the power $M$ and taking limits of both sides,

\begin{align}
\prod_i^M(1+x_i) &\leq \left(1+\frac{L}{M}\right)^M \\
\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \prod_i^M(1+x_i) & \leq \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{L}{M}\right)^M \\
\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \prod_i^M(1+x_i) & \leq e^L
\end{align}

Is my proof correct? I'm worried about the step which I take the limits of both sides of the inequality.

Comment: You can get the same bound slightly more simply by using the Taylor series for $e^x$ to say that $1+x\leq e^x$ when $x>0$ (even though the inequality actually holds for all $x$), Then $prod (1+x_i)\leq \prod e^{x_i} = e^{\sum x_i}$

Comment: Nice, that's very interesting

Comment: I disagree with the description of this argument as "perfect" in the accepted answer. There are some emendations that could be made, and that are well worth being aware of. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write $\prod^\infty_i(1+x_i)$ is monotone increasing.

But $\prod^\infty_i(1+x_i)$ is merely a number. What does it mean to say a number is monotone increasing? What I presume you mean is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^M (1+x_i) 
$$
(with $M$ rather than $\infty$ in the superscript) is a monotone increasing function of $M$.

You say $\sum^M_{i=1} x_i≤L$ for some $M\in\mathbb N.$ But here you ought to say for **all** $M\in \mathbb N.$

Other than that your argument is good.

I also like this way:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^M (1+x_i) \le \prod_{i=1}^M e^{x_i} = e^{\sum_{i=1}^M x_i}
$$
and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Taking limit is okay because both limit exist. Your proof seems perfect.